# How to find get the name of a variable, of class instance inside the class.

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I don't really think this is possibly, but who know I may get surprised.

There is no way to explain it, unless I get into the code fast.

```
class foo
{
   static function __callStatic($func, $arg)
   {
       //some magic here. 
   }
} 



  $foo = foo::bar(); 
  $bar = foo::bar();
  $x   = foo::bar();
```

here is my expected output.

```
  echo $foo;  // foo
  echo $bar;  // bar
  echo $x;    // x
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not present at that time. Only after the method call.

Test it:

```
class foo
{
   static function __callStatic($func, $arg)
   {
       print_r($GLOBALS);
   }
}
```

But why you need the var name?